# Discord.py - Can't get a newly created guild

Tags: python, discord.py

Goal: To get a guild that the bot just created by ID.
Expected: Print the guild name
Actual: Prints None

```
import discord
intents = discord.Intents(guilds=True)

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = await client.create_guild("Test Guild")
    print(guild) # Test Guild

    time.sleep(10) # I don't know why I tried this but I thought it could be a speed problem???

    g = client.get_guild(int(guild.id))
    print(guild) # None



client.run('Token')
```

Comment: What does `create_guild` return? no errors?

Comment: Yeah and the guild creates like normal

Answer (score 0):

You can try and loop through every guild the bot is in with:

```py
    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(guild.id)
```

This returns the IDs of the guilds and should also give out your IDs. Be aware that there is a limit (max. 10)